# Routing rails Simple Search to a listings page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have implemented a simple rails search which is searching my DB and displaying the results just fine. However, I am not fully understanding how to route my search query to a new page.

I have used rails scaffolding to create this particular section of my site:

```
class DogSearchesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_dog_search, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /dog_searches
  # GET /dog_searches.json
  def index
    @dog_searches = DogSearch.where(["dog LIKE ? ","%#{params[:search]}%"])
  end

  # GET /dog_searches/1
  # GET /dog_searches/1.json
  def show
    @dog_search = DogSearch.find(params[:city])
  end
```

index.html.rb

```
  <%= form_tag dog_searches_path, :method => 'get', :class => 'search-form' do %>
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'homesearch', :placeholder => 'Enter search term' %>
    <%= my_button_to '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>', {}, :class => "fa fa-search" %>
  <% end %>
```

I have created a page in `dog_searches/listing` and added this to my Routes file as `get 'dog_searches/listing'`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commonly, search results will go to the index page with params.  If you ever want to show a list of dog_searches, filtered or paged, it's a common approach to use the index action and view for all of this.

But, that said, if you want to render the listing page, you may want to set the form to that page

```
# routes.rb

resources :dog_searches do
  get :listing, :on => :collection
end
```

In the view - notice the url change

```
  <%= form_tag listing_dog_searches_path, :method => 'get', :class => 'search-form' do %>
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'homesearch', :placeholder => 'Enter search term' %>
    <%= my_button_to '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>', {}, :class => "fa fa-search" %>
  <% end %>
```

Then in the controller, you'd have a very similar action to index.

```
def listing
  @dog_searches = DogSearch.where(["dog LIKE ? ","%#{params[:search]}%"])
end
```

But again, can index handle all of this for you instead?

Comment: This is great and works well. I think I'll be looking at using the index if this is common practise as it doesn't make sense to deviate. When the search is run, the page design is intended to be different which is why I am looking at listing separate to the index. Still learning the process of routing with Rails and this has definitely baffled me.

Comment: There are times where you want different views for the same results - eg it's common to have a csv or excel version of an index page.  I can see other uses.  You can treat both pages as lists - just link to the other page by changing the the action and leaving the other params alone - ie `link_to(params.merge(:action => :listing))` from the index page after its rendered.  And, lastly, you can redirect to the listing page from the index page if you need to.  That option is not very common.  Instead, you may want to have a 'search_form' page and submit to index.

Answer (score 0):

What is the directory where your form is, and which new page do you want to route your search `query` or `result` to?

By default, rails render the file with the same name as the controller action.

Therefore, if the controller action that is doing the search is the `index` action in `DogSearchesController`, then the view file is the  `dog_searches/index.html.erb`

On the other hand, if you want the view to be `dog_searches/listing.html.erb`, then you may want to create a `listing` action in the `DogSearchesController` and move your search inside it as follow:

```
def listing
  @dog_searches = DogSearch.where(["dog LIKE ? ","%#{params[:search]}%"])
end
```

and let your search form point to this action:

```
  <%= form_tag listing_dog_searches_path, :method => 'get', :class => 'search-form' do %>
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'homesearch', :placeholder => 'Enter search term' %>
    <%= my_button_to '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>', {}, :class => "fa fa-search" %>
  <% end %>
```

Note here that I'm assuming that the path to the `listing` action is the `listing_dog_searches_path`.

Hope this throws some light into it?